# Left Join Mysql query resulting wrong

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a mysql left join query . This query runs ok . But the left joined table not getting values . Please go through below query . I am working in C#

```
void getstuinfo()
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("select stumaster.stuname,"+
                "stumaster.lname,"+
                "stumaster.fname,"+
                "stumaster.mname,"+
                "stumaster.fa_calty,"+
                "stumaster.sex,"+
                "castmaster.castdisp,"+
                "stumaster.castcode,"+
                "stumaster.nwscs "+
                "from stumaster "+ 
                " left join castmaster  on stumaster.castcode = castmaster.castcode "+
                " where grno = " + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text).ToString(), con_db.con);
                MySqlDataReader dr1 = com.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr1.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr1.Read())
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = (dr1[("stuname")].ToString());
                        textBox4.Text = (dr1["lname"]).ToString();
                        textBox5.Text = (dr1["fname"]).ToString();
                        textBox6.Text = (dr1["mname"]).ToString();
                        comboBox5.Text = (dr1["fa_calty"]).ToString();
                        comboBox1.Text = (dr1["castdisp"]).ToString();
                        textBox7.Text = (dr1["castcode"]).ToString();
                        textBox9.Text = (dr1["nwscs"]).ToString();
                        string wsex = (dr1["sex"]).ToString();

                        if (wsex == "M")
                        {
                            radioButton1.Checked = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            radioButton2.Checked = true;
                        }
                    }
                    dr1.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not a Valid G.R.No.", " Student Information ");
                    dr1.Close();
                    textBox1.Focus();
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Date is Invalid  ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you provide the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to give the table name with grno

ie

```
stumaster.grno   = conditiion
```

Comment: thanks for the replay . I have corrected it but no result . Means it is not showing " castmaster.castdisp " Value rest query execute ok .

Comment: if all the values are populating then check wither the castdisp has value or not dont know about mysql bt in sqlserver we use isnull(castdisp ,0) means if the value is null then replace the result with 0 for that column

Comment: Check wither the column has a value or not cos what c# will do is it will change null to empty string and that may be the reason that you are not fetching data in only that column since you are using left outer join it will include the NULL values as well

Comment: found the problem . I have changed  stumaster.castcode = castmaster.castcode  to  trim(stumaster.castcode) = trim(castmaster.castcode).  IT solved my problem . Thanks